# Formatting MySQL output in online IDE

Tags: mysql, sql-server, output-formatting

Test platform Used - [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/) | MySQL/MSSQL

Recently attempted an code assessment for a job post involving SQL questions. I was able to get the correct output for the problem statement but the required output was ***formatted in a tabular format*** - tabs between values.

```
    val1    val2    val3
    val4    val5    val6
```

Only way I know how to achieve something similar is by using ***mysql -t or --table*** commands, none of which could be used there.

Code was in the simple query format

```
     *cte declaration*
     select col1, avg(col2), avg(col3), sum(col4)
     from cte
     group by col1
     ; (or GO)     /*end of query*/
```

**Has anyone come across a similar issue?** I would love some help regarding this.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: code is not relevant. Still I will add more.

Comment: As a job evaluation, I'd hope this is a trick question. The database gives you data. The client code or reporting tool should worry about things like tabs between values.